# Get Blender X,Y,Z and Bounding Box with script

Tags: scripting

I need to get the x,y,z values of an object as well as the bounding box through a script. So far I have the area and volume with the following code:

```
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_object(bpy.context.object, bpy.context.scene)
area = str(sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces))
volume = str(bm.calc_volume())
```

I tried something like this for the bounding box:

```
bb = str(bm.dimensions())
```

or

```
bb = bpy.data.objects["test2-2"].dimensions
```

but neither have worked. As far as the x,y,z values go I'm stumped. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you just need to specify which attribute to get from the dimensions (bpy.data.objects["test2-2"].dimensions.x for example)
As for location, use bpy.data.objects["test2-2"].location.z

Comment: wow, that totally makes sense, and works well. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Wasn't sure if that's all you wanted to know - added it as an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both location and dimensions are vectors, meaning they'll return a vector of three values (x, y, z). If you want to get only one axis, use:

```
bpy.data.objects['object_name'].location.x
bpy.data.objects['object_name'].location.y
bpy.data.objects['object_name'].location.z
```

The dimensions of the bounding box of that object:

```
bpy.data.objects['object_name'].dimensions.x
bpy.data.objects['object_name'].dimensions.y
bpy.data.objects['object_name'].dimensions.z
```

You can set the values by simply using `obj.location.x = 5`, or if you would like to set all three axes, you can do `obj.location = (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: If I try to use `dimension.x` in a driver variable, it doesn't recognize it as a valid data path. I have to write dimensions[0] to get the x value.

Answer (score 28):

To include parenting and drivers, use this for the actual object location / origin:

```
ob = bpy.context.object

ob.matrix_world.translation # or .to_translation()
```

You can get the bounding box corners [Object.bound_box](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=bound_box#bpy.types.Object.bound_box) in object-space and multiply by [Object.matrix_world](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=matrix_world#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world) for world-space:

```
from mathutils import Vector
bbox_corners = [ob.matrix_world @ Vector(corner) for corner in ob.bound_box]
# bbox_corners = [ob.matrix_world * Vector(corner) for corner in ob.bound_box]  # Use this in V2.79 or older
```

Note that the bounding box is not axis aligned.

Comment: Starting from 2.8 `TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector' types`: needs to be: `bbox_corners = [ob.matrix_world @ Vector(corner) for corner in ob.bound_box]`

Comment: @oneiros I also encountered this error did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @AvivSham it's right there: `bbox_corners = [ob.matrix_world @ Vector(corner) for corner in ob.bound_box]` (change the asterisk `*` to an at symbol `@`)