# how to get 3D vertex bounding box around the object in python

Tags: python, objects, image

I have a vehicle model, the 3D bounding box of the vehicle model contains the 3D coordinates of each vertex.  My question is would it possible to get the 3D bounding box coordinates, which is a 8 vertex vector [8,2] directly from python. With this bounding box coordinates, I want to do two things, firstly calculate the pose of the object, secondly find a way to calculate the image pixel coordinate corresponding to each 3D vertex.

I have found some related work,
this [Save the 2D bounding box of an object in rendered image to a text file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/save-the-2d-bounding-box-of-an-object-in-rendered-image-to-a-text-file) shows how to get 2D bounding box coordinates around the image, however it is 2D bounding box. 
 Furthermore, [Display bounding box around objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/display-bounding-box-around-objects?rq=1)
can show us how to display the 3D bounding box around the object, it doesn't tell me how to get vertex in python.

Comment: you may be interested in the addon made for [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14188/935).

Answer (score 1):

For the 8 bounding box corners in local coordinates:

```
ob.bound_box
```

Transformation matrix from local to global:

```
ob.matrix_world
```

Both together:

```
bbverts = [ob.matrix_world * Vector(bbvert) for bbvert in ob.bound_box]
```

or

```
bbverts = [ob.matrix_world @ Vector(bbvert) for bbvert in ob.bound_box]
```

for versions 2.8 and above.

Comment: what I mean is not the x,y,z of the object, but the coordinates of 3D bounding box, which is a 16 elements array of 8 vertex at the corners of the object

Comment: I have edited the answer. It is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8459/get-blender-x-y-z-and-bounding-box-with-script.

Comment: Should this not be `ob.matrix_world * Vector(bbvert)`? (`@` instead of `*` in newer versions)