# Does bound_box take into account an object's location?

Tags: python

I am trying to write code to align an object to another. To do so, I calculate the objects' bounding boxes like so:

```
bbox_a =  [Vector(bbvert) @ mesh_object_a.matrix_world for bbvert in mesh_object_a.bound_box]
bbox_b =  [Vector(bbvert) @ mesh_object_b.matrix_world for bbvert in mesh_object_b.bound_box]
```

then compare the min or max along the chosen axis, and move the location of the second object accordingly.

However I've noticed that, even if `object_b` has a location of

```
<Vector (-4.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
```

`bbox_b` is

```
[
 Vector((-1.4142135381698608, 0.0, -1.0)), Vector((-1.4142135381698608, 0.0, 1.0)),
 Vector((0.0, 1.4142135381698608, 1.0)), Vector((0.0, 1.4142135381698608, -1.0)),
 Vector((0.0, -1.4142135381698608, -1.0)), Vector((0.0, -1.4142135381698608, 1.0)),
 Vector((1.4142135381698608, 0.0, 1.0)), Vector((1.4142135381698608, 0.0, -1.0))
]
```

i.e.: it looks like it has ignored location.

Did I get it right? do I have to apply location on top of matrix_world in order to find out the actual bounding box of the object? and (to future-proof the question) is it so for all other transforms too?

Comment: The correct syntax is `matrix @ vector`, not the other way around

Comment: @Gorgious - yes it does, thanks. I got the ```vector @ matrix``` thing from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88914/how-to-get-3d-vertex-bounding-box-around-the-object-in-python

Comment: You're right, the answer you linked is wrong. (the error was pointed out in the comments) It will be edited, thanks :)

Comment: @Gorgious - I edited it already but I'd appreciate any check, as a newbie

Comment: Alright, you're all set. Thanks for the feedback :)