# Get dimensions of a rotated object

Tags: python

I want to make multiple copies of a complex mesh and space them apart so that they barely touch. What I have now is a script like this:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
src_obj = bpy.context.active_object
x_size = src_obj.dimensions.x

for i in range (1,5):
    new_obj = src_obj.copy()
    new_obj.data = src_obj.data.copy()
    new_obj.animation_data_clear()
    new_obj.location.x += i * x_size
    C.collection.objects.link(new_obj)
```

However, if I rotate the original object around the z axis, x_size doesn't really refer to the x dimensions in world space anymore, so the spacing between the objects is off. How do I get the dimensions along the world space instead?

Comment: You can use bound box of object `ob.bound_box`. Find min and max values of X in 8 vectors of bounding box. max - min will give you desired result.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8470/115433

Comment: I tried doing it like in the link, but that gives me the distance between diagonal points, that's not the size along the world x-axis, but something bigger. What I want is to get a bounding box where one side is oriented along the x axis.

Comment: @dan link gives the bbox in global coordinates but (shapewise is still) axis aligned to the local coords of the object. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223858/how-do-i-get-the-bounding-box-of-all-objects-in-a-scene

Comment: @batFINGER I know, that's why I said it doesn't really apply to my problem. For now I just apply the rotation to the object before doing anything else, that sidesteps the problem.